# Reference all paths in single linux script - like a header file for better portability

Tags: command-line, scripts, csh

Shell Scripting newbie here.

Please bear with me.

**Linux 3.0.101-108.87-default x86_64**

I have ***Script1.sh*** which is referencing folders . I am trying to include all these paths in the script in a single ***headerscript.sh*** and then reference the ***headerscript.sh*** in  ***Script1.sh***

**I am doing this right now**

```
Script1.sh
 
setenv SCRIPT  /../site/SCRIPTS
setenv TOP     /../site/TOP
setenv SUB1    /../site/../.../SUB1
setenv SUB2    /../site/../.../SUB2
setenv SUB3    /../site/../.../SUB3
setenv SUB4    /../site/../.../SUB4
setenv SUB5    /../site/../.../SUB5
```

**Instead I want to do something like this**

```
Script1.sh 

include headerscript.sh
```

**and headerscript.sh will look something like this**

```
headerscript.sh

setenv SCRIPT  /../site/SCRIPTS
setenv TOP     /../site/TOP
setenv SUB1    /../site/../.../SUB1
setenv SUB2    /../site/../.../SUB2
setenv SUB3    /../site/../.../SUB3
setenv SUB4    /../site/../.../SUB4
setenv SUB5    /../site/../.../SUB5
```

This allows me to make the script modular by just including ***headerscript.sh*** in another script and easier to debug.

What should I be doing ?

I don't want to include this in .alias

Comment: Updated - thanks for correction

Comment: You didn't mention your OS & release, however given the oldest *supported* kernel for on-topic systems here is currently 4.15, your system appears very old (3.0 was from a 2011 based system, a decade old) so I hope your system is off-line.

Comment: Do you mean to [include one file from another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192305/4970442)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "include" one script from another you should use `.` (dot operator) or `source` (depending on your shell).

So you would use in `Script1.sh`

```
. headerscript.sh
```

References:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094271/using-dot-or-source-while-calling-another-script-what-is-the-difference

[https://ss64.com/bash/source.html#:~:text=source%20is%20a%20synonym%20for,available%20after%20the%20script%20completes](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html#:%7E:text=source%20is%20a%20synonym%20for,available%20after%20the%20script%20completes).

Comment: Script Works as intended. Thank you so much :)